# MapDB flash friendliness

Tags: java, mapdb

I'm exploring MapDB utility to be used as a off-heap java cache backed by a SSD. Can someone suggest if it supports following:

1. Is device access to SSD device "flash friendly" i.e. access are pages aligned.
2. Does it allow inserting keys to the device in a batch mode. (All I was wondering if I can avoid performing db.commit() after insert of every single key).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Not right now, key align should be added in 1.1 in a few weeks.

2) yes, use Data Pump. You can also disable transactions and get very fast insert mode